# why not use Function arguments in php laravel lazyCollection

Tags: php, laravel, arguments

this is my code

```
public function createUsersNumberTest($number){
    $collect=LazyCollection::make(function($number){
        dd($number);
    }
    );
    $collect->collect();
}
```

why i,m not use $number in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have an [anonymous](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) function inside it does not see your `$number` pass it with `use`

```
public function createUsersNumberTest($number){
$collect=LazyCollection::make(function() use ($number) {
    dd($number);
}
);
$collect->collect();
}
```